# Show $X_1^5+X_1^2X_2+X_1X_2+X_2$ is irreducible

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

For a field $K$, is the polynomial $X_1^5+X_1^2X_2+X_1X_2+X_2$ irreducible in $K[X_1,X_2]$?

I think I have to show it for $K(X_1)[X_2]$ but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: That's the context, yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use Eisenstein's criterion with the ideal $\langle X_2\rangle.$
- Now you can say that your polynomial is irreducible in $K(X_1)[X_2]$.
- Use that the polynomial is primitive to conclude that it is irreducible in $K[X_1X_2]$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Use Eisenstein's criterion (from left to right $X_2\nmid1$, $X_2\mid X_2$, $X_2\mid X_2$ and $X_2^2\nmid X_2$). Then use Gauss' lemma to pass back from the fraction field (the polynomial is primitive).